# How to achieve horizontal as well as vertical layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I wanted to have following type of layout in android application:

--Horizontal Scroll Items (music albums) 
--Horizontal Scroll Items (video albums)
--Some Text
--Vertical List (playlist 1)
--Vertical List (playlist 2)

This complete UI may be beyond vertical screen size so there should be vertical scroll on screen

Could any one please tell me how can I achieve this type of interface. At first I thought have everything under a ScrollView, but with this ListView doesn't seem to work under ScrollView.

Please suggest me any other alternative to achieve this.